# Errors while starting CQ server

Tags: osgi, aem

I've noticed these errors while starting cq instances on my box. Everything seems to run fine, I'm just curious what I can do to help resolve seeing these errors on startup. The bundles vary.

```
ERROR: [Thread[OsgiInstallerImpl,5,main]] Waited too long to acquire lock for bundle com.day.cq.cq-polling-importer [168] owned by null (lockcount=0); giving up.
ERROR: [Thread[OsgiInstallerImpl,5,main]] Waited too long to acquire lock for bundle com.day.cq.cq-jobs-core [169] owned by null (lockcount=0); giving up.
ERROR: [Thread[OsgiInstallerImpl,5,main]] Waited too long to acquire lock for bundle com.day.cq.cq-rewriter [170] owned by null (lockcount=0); giving up.
ERROR: [Thread[OsgiInstallerImpl,5,main]] Waited too long to acquire lock for bundle com.day.cq.cq-mailer [171] owned by null (lockcount=0); giving up.
ERROR: [Thread[FelixDispatchQueue,5,main]] Waited too long to acquire the global lock own by Thread[FelixStartLevel,5,main]; giving up.
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** *Adobe tech support has told me that the message is harmless and the result of a known bug.  The issue, and the message, are fixed as of CQ version 5.6.  You can safely ignore the message.*

Original answer:
My belief is that this is the FelixDispatchQueue waiting for the lock to be released, and it keeps attempting to get the lock until it is successful.  The timeout appears to be when it tosses another line in the log before trying again.

In my system I always see these messages, yet Felix is always operating properly.

I've found nothing else on the interwebs to indicate that this is anything other than a somewhat scary looking, but entirely normal, information message.

Comment: sorry for the long delay in accepting, thank you for the response from adobe tech support. The error seemed harmless as we developed with it for awhile, but it's good to know it wasn't us and it was a product flaw. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Goto OSGI console and check if the bundle is active.
I've noticed these errors on my machine as well, my guess is that there are dependencies which are not getting resolved within the specified time.
In my case, it got auto resolved after sometime.